# Python black style discrepancy

Tags: python, pep8

I am using [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to format my python code. I observed the following behavior. I admit that it is a very specific case but it goes on my nerves.

Let's suppose I have the following code:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
"first",
["second"],
)
```

`black` does not change that. But, if I remove the trailing comma after `["second"]`:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
"first",
["second"]
)
```

`black` makes a nice reordering:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("first", ["second"])
```

On the other hand, let us see the following:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
"This is a very long line. Black will not be able to to a linebreak here.",
["second"],
)
```

In this case, again, `black` does not change anything. So far, so good. Now, I remove the trailing comma after `["second"]` again:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
"This is a very long line and black will not be able to do a line break here.",
["second"]
)
```

As the line is too long, `black` does not do a nice reordering into one line as before. But instead, `black` adds a trailing comma after the `["second"]`:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
"This is a very long line and black will not be able to do a line break here.",
["second"],
)
```

I do not like that. When I am confronted with such lists in my code, I always tend to remove the trailing comma to enforce one line reordering. But then, in most of the cases, `black` adds it again ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The black behavior is expected from my understanding, because one of the purpose is to limit the number of changes inside a git diff.

If the line is too long, you already are in a multiline writing. And if you are in a multiline writing, then it should end with a coma.

That way if you add elements in the tuple, list, … or arguments in method or function, it will not generate a diff for the line where you add the coma.

If a contrario you are in a mono-line writing that is not too long, black will consider if you have added a trailing coma. If trailing comma, it will go to multi-line, if not it will encourage mono-line.

```
a = [1, 2,]
# goes to
a = [
    1,
    2,
]

# and

a = [1, 2]
# remains:
a = [1, 2]
```

Comment: Okay, I see the point with the `git` diff. Thanks a lot! Nevertheless, I would prefer to force a mono-line wherever it is possible ...

Comment: I feel like then you could like the   `-C, --skip-magic-trailing-comma
                                  Don't use trailing commas as a reason to
                                  split lines.` option! It will enforce the one line even with trailing commas if possible!

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I want.

Comment: The downside to using `skip-magic-trailing-comma` is black will reformat lists that are intentionally multi-lined with commas into single line, if it can fit within the length limit.